# I have this sample response returned from an API. I'm using Lodash's _.groupBy to convert the data to the grouped output. sample response is like

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm, lodash

```
[
{
"airbill_pieces": 1,
"airbillnbr": 81061140,
"load_point": "IND",
"manifestnbr": 1907521,
"handled_pieces": 5,
"manifest_weight": 12548,
},
{
"airbill_pieces": 2,
"airbillnbr": 81061158,
"load_point": "IND",
"manifestnbr": 1907522,
"handled_pieces": 12,
"manifest_weight": 12368,
}
]
```

required response as

```
{
        "data": {
          "load_point": "IND",
          "airbill_pieces": "sum of all "handled_pieces" / sum of all "airbill_pieces",
          "manifest_weight": sum of "manifest_weight",
          "manifestnbr": 1907521,
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "data": {
              "airbillnbr": 81061140,
              "manifest_weight": 12548,
              "manifestnbr": 1907521,
              "airbill_pieces": 1,
            }
          },
          {
            "data": {
              "airbillnbr": 81061158,
              "manifest_weight": 12368,
              "manifestnbr": 1907522,
              "airbill_pieces": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

I am using the below code to get the desire output but fail to get exact format. it groups the load_point as a keypair values but i need a object followed by "data" key.

```
let result = _.chain(outboundAirbills)
        .groupBy("load_point")
        .pairs()
       .map( (currentItem) => {
           return _.object(_.zip(["data", "children"], currentItem));
       })
       .value();
   console.log(result);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting an array of such output values, one for each `load_point` in the initial data, or an object keyed off the `load_point`, with values as in your expected output?  In other words, what do you expect if your input includes items with different `load_point`s?

Comment: Your summary section includes a `manifestnbr`, but it's summarizing items with different ones.  Do you want the first one only?  Or should this be removed from the summary?  Also, I see no attempt here at making a summary.

Comment: Yes, I expect an array of such output values. I need to group based on load_point. i need load_point in only first object as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version in vanilla JS, using two simple helpers, `sum` which calculates the sum of an array of numbers, and `group` which groups items of an array into subarrays for which the supplied function returns the same value.  (It's like lodash's `groupBy` followed by `values`, but curried, more like Ramda):

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const group = (fn) => (xs) => Object .values (
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = (a [fn (x)] || []) .concat (x)), a), {})
)

const restructure = (xs) => 
  group (x => x .load_point) (xs) .map (g => ({
    data: {
      load_point: g [0] .load_point,
      airbill_pieces: sum (g .map (x => x .handled_pieces))
                    / sum (g .map (x => x .airbill_pieces)),
      manifest_weight:sum (g .map (x => x .manifest_weight)),
      // manifestnbr: g [0] .manifestnbr,
    },
    children: g .map (({load_point, manifest_weight, manifestnbr, airbill_pieces}) => 
      ({data: {load_point, manifest_weight, manifestnbr, airbill_pieces}})
    )
  }))

const data = [{airbill_pieces: 1, airbillnbr: 81061140, load_point: "IND", manifestnbr: 1907521, handled_pieces: 5, manifest_weight: 12548, }, {airbill_pieces: 2, airbillnbr: 81061158, load_point: "IND", manifestnbr: 1907522, handled_pieces: 12, manifest_weight: 12368}]

console .log (restructure (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We first group the data based on `load_point` and then, for each group, summarize the result in `data` and collect a subset of the fields inside elements of a `children` array.

If you do want the first `manifestnbr`, just uncomment the relevant line.  But it's redundant data since you have it in the first child, and it's incomplete data, since it ignores all the values after the first one; still, it might be necessary for your needs.

You could definitely write this with lodash's `groupBy`, but this shows how easy it is to maintain your own collection of tools.  (I'm a primary author of another collection of tools, [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com).)  Note that if you wanted to have both `groupBy` (which returns an object keyed off the results of the function) and `group`, which just groups the array into subarrays), you could build `group` atop `groupBy` trivially like this:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = (a [fn (x)] || []) .concat (x)), a), {})

const group = (fn) => (xs) => 
  Object .values (groupBy (fn) (xs))
```

Comment: Thanks scott, its working here but when I copy those codes on our angular application it shows that Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339). i am trying to resolve this but could you please run this code to any sample angular application.

Comment: I really don't know Typescript at all, and haven't touched Angular in years.  My guess is that you will need to give a type to `group`.  It would take a function from an arbitrary type, `A` to a String, and return a function from an array of items of type `A` to an array of arrays of items of type `A`.  In Hindley-Milner notation, `(a -> String) -> [a] -> [[a]]`.  I don't know that this would solve all your problems, but it might help.

Comment: the error has been resolved and the results are awesome. thanks scott.  such a beautiful answer- just one at all.

Comment: Glad it helps.  What did it take to resolve that error?

Comment: i just declare add type any to "gas .map ((g:any) => ({})"